# How to write 2 consequent recursions with Completable future?

Tags: java, recursion, completable-future, chaining

I have the following code which tries to get a /ready endpoint of a service until it returns OK and then makes a call to that service when it is available:

```
  @PostConstruct
  void registerMetadata() {
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(this::getServiceReady, executor)
        .thenRunAsync(() -> registerWithRetry(0), executor);
  }

  private void registerWithRetry(int retryAttempt) {
  serviceRegistrationOperations.registerService(serviceMetadataMedia)
        .thenAccept(data -> {
          this.isMetadataRegistered = true;
        }).whenComplete((data, ex) -> {
          if (ex != null) {
            Throwable cause = ExceptionUtils.cleanseTop(ex);
            String message = cause.getMessage();
            }
            int delayInSeconds = getDelaySecondsBeforeNextRetry(retryAttempt);
            log.error("Failed to register metadata: {}, will retry again in {} seconds", message, delayInSeconds, cause);
            CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> registerWithRetry(retryAttempt + 1), new DelayedExecutor(delayInSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS, executor));
          }
        });
  }

  private CompletableFuture<Boolean> getServiceReady() {
    log.info("Getting the readiness of the service");
    if (this.exitFlag) {
      return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
    }
    return healthOperations.getReadiness()
        .thenApply(isServiceReady -> {
         this.exitFlag = true;
          return true;
        }).whenComplete((result, ex) -> {
          if (ex != null) {
            log.error("service is not up");
            CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> getServiceReady(), new DelayedExecutor(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS, executor));
          }
        });
  }
```

However, it seems that the code never waits for the first recursion to complete (meaning the `healthOperations.getServiceReady()` to return true). I want to make it so that it first waits for the first recursion to finish and then to go to the registerWithRetry method. Can you help me figure out how to write the first recursion so that the program waits for it and then moves on with the second one?

I tried different ways to achieve this. For my use case `block(healthOperations.getServiceReady())` doesn't work, so my guess is that it has to be a chain of events.

Comment: `iServiceReady` is has a spelling error, which is one source of compilation errors

Comment: @michid I updated the question. I am more interested in the approach that can be used to chain two recursions with completable future.  Please take another look at the updated question.

Comment: You're returning a `CompletableFuture<Boolean>`, and this should _not_ block the method from returning. You also don't need the `Boolean` for this purpose, a `CompletableFuture<Void>` works fine (since completion is akin to being ready). The only lines in `#getServiceReady` that are needed are the `return healthOperations.getServiceReady()` and the entire `.whenComplete` block. Now you said "recursive" - I would hope that your posted `#getServiceReady` is not calling itself eventually, as that will stackoverflow.

Comment: @Rogue, I amended the code, getServiceReady does call itself if the getReadiness() call returns false. it should stop the recursion once the getReadiness call returns true. Can you please give me a sample code how to achieve the 2 recursions call?

Comment: I see then, you have a use-case for `CompletableFuture#thenApplyAsync`. I'll write up an example, though I've just had something dropped in my lap for the next hour. You'll see that answer in a couple hours.

Comment: One further question: Is it strictly necessary that you only retry when an exception occurs? Normally you'd allow an exception to propagate up to whoever initiated the first `CompletableFuture<T>`, that way they can also be the ones to handle the exceptions that _do_ occur. In this same vein, does `healthOperations.getReadiness()` only ever return `true` when it completes normally?

Comment: @Rogue healthOperations.getReadiness() should only return true when it completes normally. It actually returns CompletableFuture<Boolean>, so either true or false. However, the API returns 200 OK is the service is ready to accept traffic and 503 if it isn't. This is what the getReadiness looks like. See in the next comment

Comment: return CompletableFuture
            .runAsync(() -> {
                if (isReady) {
                    Response.ok().data(Boolean.TRUE.toString()).end(routingContext);
                } else {
                 Response.create().status(SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE).end(routingContext);
                }
            }, executor);

Comment: It is necessary that we retry when the getReadiness does not return true (200 OK). @Rogue thank you for your help sincerely. I have been struggling with this for 2 days now.

Comment: @Rogue just to summarise what I said, the getReadiness() is a very simple method that returns 200 or 503. We need to retry until it returns 200. As far as I can see in the code, the response is deserialised to a boolean and you can see the getReadiness code sample above. Thank you once again.